# Поиск файла exe

Tags: c++

Написать приложение, которое может просматривать каталоги, запускать любой EXE-файл и принудительно закрывать его по истечении времени, заданном пользователем.
Не получается найти файлы с расширением exe

```
String S;

//Структура описывает файл
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

//дескриптор потока
HANDLE hf=FindFirstFile((Form5->Edit2->Text).c_str(), &FindFileData);//путь указываем где искать
INT i=0;

if (hf==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    ShowMessage("Папка не найдена");
    return 1;
}

do
{
    if (strstr((char*)FindFileData.cFileName,".exe") != NULL)//не работает условие..файлы есть но не находит
    {
        S=Form5->ListBox1->Items->Strings[Form5->ListBox1->ItemIndex];
        ShowMessage("Нашел");
    }
}
while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData));

FindClose(hf);
```

Не работает условие `if (strstr((char*)FindFileData.cFileName,".exe") != NULL)`, хотя файлы есть.

Comment: А в чём вопрос? (И почему вы пользуетесь WinAPI, а не стандартной библиотекой?)

Comment: надо через winapi... не работает условие там где strstr()

Comment: помогите исправить ошибку

Comment: Что в записано в (Form5->Edit2->Text).c_str(),?

Comment: (1) Почему надо? (2) Ну вот так и напишите в вопросе. И укажите, какая именно ошибка.

Comment: Берите отладчик и смотрите что у вас в strstr передается...

Comment: Form5->Edit2->Text).c_str() это путь каталога....Я пытаюсь найти файл с расширением exe и вывесте сообщение на экран а не срабатывает

Comment: я так и пишу путь к каталогу...сперва нахожу все файлы в каталоге заношу их названия в ListBox а затем мне нужно открыть exe файл из этого каталога название которого выберу в Listbox/
Ну вот идея такая найти файл с расширением exe а потом сравнить с выбраным в Listbox если совпадают то открыть.

Comment: попробуйте написать не ".exe", а "*.exe"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Как следует из обсуждения в комментариях, в функцию FindFirstFile передаётся путь к каталогу. Но согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) здесь должен быть путь и маска файлов. Если нужны все файлы, вызовите эту функцию так:

```
FindFirstFile((Form5->Edit2->Text + "\\*.*").c_str(), &FindFileData);
```

Если же вы хотите выбрать только exe-файлы, то так:

```
FindFirstFile((Form5->Edit2->Text + "\\*.exe").c_str(), &FindFileData);
```

В последнем случае проверка расширения не нужна - найденные файлы уже будут иметь требуемое расширение.